# Bash script to connect to Teletalk internet

Tags: shell, shell-script, ubuntu, elementary-os

I'm running Elementary OS(based on Ubuntu 12.04), and I have to connect to the internet in a peculiar style. I use a Teletalk modem to connect to the internet. Unfortunately, the modem gets recognized as CD and I have to un-mount the modem from the file manager once, then after a moment the modem gets recognized as CD again and I un-mount it again. After that, after a moment, in the network section, there comes Teletalk 3G connection 1. I click it and after all work, the laptop finally connects to the internet. Is there any Bash script or something like that so that I can automate atleast some part of the work?

Comment: Are you sure that automating this is what you want? Wouldn't it make slightly more sense to resolve the issue so that the modem is recognised correctly at first attempt?

Comment: It is probably a bug with [usb-modeswitch](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/). The program can be called by hand.

Comment: Can you please explain what to do? I don't know what to do... I've previously searched on how to connect to internet using teletalk, and they say to either use the method I am using or install teletalk gui software, which requires using qt3(yes.. qt3) and if I use that software, I can't use Software Center and friends.. which is sad. And another problem with the gui is that after clicking connect, it takes a long time to actually connect. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you solve your problem? I think your modem is detected as a CD first for the Zero CD feature of the modem. Your modem is detected as a storage media first then after installing the driver it switches to modem. So if you use your modem without installing the driver (Like as a Mobile Broadband instead) you will encounter this problem.

Normally this issue is handled by usb_modeswitch package. But you need to supply configuration / data (Like product / vendor ids before / after switching etc) of your device for usb_modeswitch to work(If those informations were not there already. It seems this is the case here).

I have written a guide on this issue. I have tried to explain What is Zero CD? How you will get your device information? What usb_modeswitch does? How you will inform about your device to the usb_modeswitch to the developer. I think you will get some leads there. Sorry its written in Bengali Language( Language of Bangladesh ). As you have asked about Teletalk 3G which is a country based product I have assumed you are a Bangladeshi and know Bengali language. Here is the link - https://aagontuk.github.io/gnulinux/teletalk3g/modem_switching.html

And for others who are facing this kind of problems. You can visit usb_modeswitch's website. It contains detailed writings about these issues and a friendly forum too.
http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/

Comment: I have updated the link.